# trying to handle firebase storage exception doesn't work (flutter)

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter, error-handling, firebase-storage

After creating the reference to my file on firebase storage I'm getting it's download URL. Since the file(image) may or may not exist I'm using *then* and *catch error*. However it still throws exception. Even the try and catch block doesn't work.

```
    StorageReference dpRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(
          'dp/' + widget.userId,
        );
    dpRef.getDownloadURL().then(
      (value) {
        setState(
          () {
            _dpImgURL = value;
          },
        );
      },
    ).catchError((e) {
      print(e.toString());
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? New to flutter, so please be gentle.

Comment: Try using a try catch block instead of then

Answer (score -2):

try catch is not working for firebase storage, no idea why, i fixed like this:

```
}, onError: (e) {
      debugPrint('Exception::: ==========>>>>>>> ${e.toString()}');
      status(null);
    });
```

it gets the exception vey well